# Confusion In Spring Security in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a custom `UserDetailService` implementor i.e. `MyCustomUserDetailService` where loadUserByName method is overridden.

I have token generator class that generates the JWT token.

> I have a class called `JWTAuthenticationFilter` that extends
> `OnceperRequestFilter` where there is a `doFilter` method where I am
> validating the token that has been generated and provided by the
> client in the header of the HttpRequest.
> Now from here is my real question starts. The code is something like this:

```
UserDetails usd=this.myCustomUserDetailService.loadByUserName(userNameFromToke);//userNameFromToke is a String that got extracted from the token that client provided.

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat=new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usd,null,usd.getAuthorities()); //Here in the password I am passing null.

upat.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upat);
```

> Question 1:
>
> ```
> `ups.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));`
> ```
>
> why we are passing the whole HTTP Request(i.e.httpRequest) rather than the userdetails
> that we extracted from the token? And why do I need this `setDetails`
> method as I have already passed the userdetails,pasword and the list
> of authorities in the constructor argument in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.
>
> Question 2:
>
> How is the setAuthentication method and UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken  working? I am passing the
> information that I have extracted from the token i.e.
> `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(upat)`; and userdetails,passowords and authorities in the constructor of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` but
> against what it is validating "upat"? Is `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`  automatically internally checking
> with the "`MyCustomUserDetailService`"?

I know the question is a bit lengthy but as I am a beginner I am trying hard to understand the mechanism behind it and I have done research on it but this confusion are not getting away. Please help. Also, suggest me how can I concise my question if you seem it's faulty.

Comment: The details adds additional, useful, information like ip-address, session information etc. to the `Authentication` object. This can be useful for logging for instance (or additional security rules you might write). The `setAuthentication` isn't validating anything, it is the common holder for SPring Security to access the current user information (basically ou are setting the current user for the current request/thread).

Comment: So I even if I skip the setAuthentication and setDetails part the client provided token will get authenticated by UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken..am I correct?

Comment: No. THe `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is just a DTO.

Comment: So there is no token authentication logic in the code snippet that I shared I guess?

Comment: The first line retrieves the user. When you have a token you are (as long as the token is valid) already authenticated.

Comment: Then why do I need UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and SecurityContextHolder? As the client is legit what these lines of codes are doing actually?

Comment: Spring Security knows about an `Authentication` **how** that `Authentication` comes into existence isn't import. Could be basic-auth, form login a JWT token or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The details in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` are totally up to you, it helps if you need more details from the authenticated user later on in your application. Like when you call `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`, you can cast this `Authentication` to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and access its details for any business purposes;
2. Your `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is not being validated against anything, you need to do it manually by either calling your `UserDetailsService` and checking the password, or injecting and calling `AuthenticationManager#authenticate` method. Spring Security [does not care](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder) how the `SecurityContextHolder` was populated. In basic scenarios, after you setting an authenticated `SecurityContext` into the `SecurityContextHolder`, the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` will take this `SecurityContext` and save it in the `HttpSession` as an attribute.
   In the next requests, this attribute will be present in your `HttpSession`, this way Spring Security loads the `SecurityContext` and sets it into the `SecurityContextHolder`.

You can get more details in the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java), but I'll point out the specific part for this question here:

```java
HttpRequestResponseHolder holder = new HttpRequestResponseHolder(request, response);
// Here Spring Security loads the SecurityContext from the HttpSession, this is done before reaching your controllers, before calling the FilterChain.
SecurityContext contextBeforeChainExecution = this.repo.loadContext(holder); 
try {
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(contextBeforeChainExecution);
    if (contextBeforeChainExecution.getAuthentication() == null) {
        logger.debug("Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext");
    }
    else {
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger
                        .debug(LogMessage.format("Set SecurityContextHolder to %s", contextBeforeChainExecution));
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
}
finally {
    // You've populated the SecurityContextHolder and it'll be available here after you application returns. So it'll get the SecurityContext and persist it in the HttpSession
    SecurityContext contextAfterChainExecution = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    // Persisting the SecurityContext in the HttpSession
    this.repo.saveContext(contextAfterChainExecution, holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
    request.removeAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED);
    this.logger.debug("Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request");
}
```

I hope this helps you to understand better how Spring Security works. There is also a [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/) that is a great source to know more about the details of the architecture.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Just curious to know..In the code snippet that I shared there is no client's token validation logic..am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, like I said you are not validating the user's credentials, just populating the `SecurityContextHolder` straight. You can validate the user password or use the `AuthenticationManager` to authenticate the user as the `Filter`s does, and, after that, if authentication is successful, you populated the `SecurityContextHolder`

Comment: Got it. Final question: If I use this line of code of AuhtenticationManager i.e. authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)); now how this method will authenticate? As I am sending only whatever client is providing me..it authenticates against what? Is it calling internally MyUserDetailsService to authenticate?

Comment: Yes, it will find an `AuthenticationProvider` that is able to authenticate it, and this provider may use your custom `UserDetailsService` to find your user credentials and check against the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

Comment: Did I answered your question? If so can you accept it? This way we can help others with the same doubt

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it was very much helpful. Upvote my question if possible