# Can I call Spring Security "/login" post method programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, spring-security, jframe

I just need to authenticate a user without a browser and an html page ...
The idea is to call the "/login" path with a post method programmatically (so that I can use the hypothetical
function login(username, password) inside of a JFrame) but i don't know how to do it.
Online I don't find anything, maybe it's just not possible because of the MVC pattern used by spring security, pls let me know.

Comment: Any specific reason for using Spring MVC? I mean there are so many tutorials on Spring Boot (Spring MVC is typically used for a different purpose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String user(Principal principal) {
    String username = principal.getName();
    System.out.println("username: " + username);
    return "Hello User";
}
```

Suppose this is the path you want to call, you can do it from client like this:

```
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/user");
    // You can get username and password from a simple form
    String auth = username + ":" + password;
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
      auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    Utente.updateSettings(CTT.getSede(), new String(encodedAuth), username);
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        
        if(statusCode == 200) {
            System.out.println("Ok you are in");
        }else {
            throw new StatusCodeException();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }catch (StatusCodeException err){
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are trying to do is authenticate a user exists or not using a Post request without fetching details from a html.
You would not need a Post request for that, you can use the HttpServletRequest that Spring provides.

```
public void authWithHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String username, String password) {
    try {
        request.login(username, password);
    } 
    catch (ServletException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while login ", e);
    }
}
```

For more details on Spring security, refer to the below GitHub project
https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do that. By default Spring Security handle a `POST` request to `/login` endpoint with `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to process the authentication request.

One example of the request using [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/):

```sh
http -f POST http://localhost:8080/login username=user password=password _csrf=your-csrf-token
```

Remember that you have to send the `CSRF` token as well as it will not be added automatically for you in this scenario.
Having this in mind, you can perform this request from anywhere you want.

Comment: I am sorry but I have never worked before with spring security and I don't really understand how to write the reqest you menctioned in java.
I mean, assuming i get username and password from the JFrame, I should pass this values to a function like login(username, password). 
Here in this function I should programmatically request in Java what you menctioned and I really don't know how to do it. Pls let me know if you would like to help me, thank you for all your assistance

Comment: You can use the `AuthenticationManager#authenticate` method to do that or even populating the `SecurityContextHolder`. You can find more in the Spring Security Reference Documentation and in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113942/confusion-in-spring-security-in-spring-boot/68116138#68116138